# How to get my animation to play in unity when my character jumps

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where the character is continuously jumping up and down. I use OnCollisionEnter() to make him jump every time he hits the ground. I am trying to invoke an animation that make the characters arms wiggle inside the function as well, like this:

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){

```
    foreach(ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts){
        rigidbody.velocity = transform.up*10;
        audio.Play();
        animation.Play ("JumpAnimation");
    }
}
```

When I run the game I get the following error:

**MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animation' attached to the "Green Bot" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Animation to the game object "Green Bot". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.**

I have an animator component attached to my "Green Bot" and the animation plays if I click Loop, but I only want it to play inside the above function. How can I check if the component is attached inside the script, as the error suggests?

UPDATE:

I've set my code to:

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){

```
    foreach(ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts){
        rigidbody.velocity = transform.up*10;
        audio.Play();
        animator.SetTrigger("Jump");
    }
}
```

and here is a snapshot of my Animator window:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the using a trigger within the animator and then calling animator.[SetTrigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html)("YourTrigger") within your OnCollisionEnter event? Within the animator you would create the aforementioned trigger parameter (boolean) and tie your animation to that.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){

  foreach(ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts){
    rigidbody.velocity = transform.up*10;
    audio.Play();
    animator.SetTrigger("Jump");
  }
}
```

The Unity3D Tutorials on [Animator Scripting](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/animation/animator-scripting) may also be a helpful reference for you as they walk through this concept in more detail including how to properly configure the animator.

Comment: I have checked out Animator Scripting, I may have to look at it again. I have updated my question to reflect your suggestions but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something in my Animator window ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have an animation component in addition to animator if you want to use animation. Play then in "size" part of animation, enter 1 and press enter. An input comes. Select your animation, that's it.

Enjoy!